# how to send mail programmatically without freezing UI

Tags: c#, winforms

i have an application that sends email by receiving a text message. I realized at the point of this code `smt.Send(mailMsg);` my UI freezes until sending process is done, this sometimes takes 2-5 min and i don't want the user to think the application has crashed or is malfunctioning. therefore i would like to know how to run that method in a backgroundworker  to avoid freezing my UI. below is relevant code thank you.

Report generating/exporting method

```
 private void Q4report()
    {
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        Output("Processing request...");
        ReportDocument cryRpt1 = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt1.Load("cryQ2.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = cryRpt1;
        crystalReportViewer2.Refresh();
        cryRpt1.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "QueryReport.pdf");
        Output("Generating report...");
        Output("Report Process Completed");
        if (i != 1)
        {
            sendMail("QueryReport.pdf", "4POS StockItem/per price list Query Report");
        }
        else if( i == 1)
        {
            Unsent_Request_sendMail("QueryReport.pdf", "4POS StockItem/per price list Query Report");
        }


    }
```

Email sending method

```
    public bool sendMail(string pdf, string subject)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        try
        {

            // To

            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(radtxtEmail.Text);
            if (sub3 != null)
            {
                string strSubject = subject;
                string strBody = "Kindly find attached your query report.";

                mailMsg.To.Add(sub3);
                mailMsg.Subject = strSubject;
                mailMsg.Body = strBody;

                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(pdf);
                mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                using (SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
                {
                    smt.Port = 587;
                    smt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(radtxtEmail.Text, radtxtboxPassword.Text);
                    smt.EnableSsl = true;

                    bool connection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

                    bool IsOnline = ModemManager.netCheck.IsOnline();

                    if (connection == true)
                    {
                        if (IsOnline == true)
                        {

                            smt.Send(mailMsg);
                            sent_insert();

                            mailMsg.Dispose();
                            attachment.Dispose();
                            Output("Report Mail successfully sent!");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Output("Internet Access Unavailable.");
                            Output("Mail process terminated.");
                            Unsent_insert();
                            mailMsg.Dispose();
                            attachment.Dispose();
                        //    btnSendMessage_Click();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Output("Network Connectivity Unavailable.");

                        Unsent_insert();

                        mailMsg.Dispose();
                        attachment.Dispose();
                  //      btnSendMessage_Click();
                        return false;
                    }

                }

                flag = true;


            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

          Output(ex.Message);

        }


        return flag;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate the sendMail method in a Task.Run block, which will start the method on a separate thread:

```
if (i != 1)
{
    Task.Run(() => sendMail("QueryReport.pdf", "4POS StockItem/per price list Query Report"));
}
```

Note that unless you save the created task, you'll have no way to monitor the status of the task for completion or cancel it if needed. If this is for a UI, I'd capture the created task as part of the parent classes state:

```
private Task sendMailTask;
```

Then attach the task created from Task.Run so you have a way to get back to the generated task if you need to:

```
 if (i != 1)
{
    this.sendMailTask = Task.Run(() => sendMail("QueryReport.pdf", "4POS StockItem/per price list Query Report"));
}
```

Alternatively, if this is being triggered as a result of a button click for example, you can await it in an async void method:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    if (i != 1)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => sendMail("QueryReport.pdf", "4POS StockItem/per price list Query Report"));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Which will still return control to the UI and run the work for sending mail in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Use BackgroundWorker to prevent freeze

Comment: i figured i had to run my email sending process is a background worker and and call backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  is my report generating method and that solved it ty.